# Update a row without affecting other rows

Tags: php, mysql

[here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv2Bt.png)

So when I clicked the (+) button and (-) button the other rows get affected as you can see in the picture of 'produced' column, what I want is, only a selected row will get affected where I click the (+) button and (-) button.

so here's the code:

```
foreach( $result as $row ) {

$data_id = $row['product_id'];
$data_product_name = $row['product_name'];
$data_price = $row['price'];
$data_total_price = $row['total'];
$data_quantity = $row['quantity'];
$data_expiration_date = $row['expiration_date'];

 echo <<<EOD
   <div class="table_row">
     <div class="table_column 1">
       Select <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_select[]" value=$data_id />
     </div>  
       <div class="table_column 2">$data_id</div>
       <div class="table_column 3">$data_product_name</div>
       <div class="table_column 4">P $data_price</div>
       <div class="table_column 5">P $data_total_price</div>
       <div class="table_column 6">$data_quantity
           <button name="button_add_quantity" class="buttons_add_subtract">+</button>
           <button name="button_subtract_quantity" class="buttons_add_subtract">-</button>
       </div>
     <div class="table_column 7">
         Expiration Date: $data_expiration_date<br>
         Time Left:
     </div>
     </div>
EOD;


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

 if (isset($_POST['button_add_quantity'])) {

   $data_quantity += 1;
   $statement_update = $pdo_connection->prepare("UPDATE finished_goods SET quantity=?
   WHERE product_id IN ('$data_id')");
   $statement_update->execute([$data_quantity]);
   header('refresh:0');

   } elseif (isset($_POST['button_subtract_quantity'])) {

   $data_quantity -= 1;
   $statement_update = $pdo_connection->prepare("UPDATE finished_goods SET quantity=?
   WHERE product_id IN ('$data_id')");
   $statement_update->execute([$data_quantity]);
   header('refresh:0');

     }

    }
   }
```

Any help will do :)

Comment: `button_add_quantity` and  `button_subtract_quantity` both are same for all rows, so it is actually one btn for all rows,

Comment: you should use either radio btn for  + and - or checkbox depending on reuirement and may have name like row1 , row2, row3 etc

Comment: btw when you submit, suppose 3 rows with + , what data do you get, all data from 3 rows (div table_row)

Comment: I don't get it, even if I change it into a table type instead of, it still has the same output all rows are affected with +

Comment: the problem is , the  + or - btn on all rows has same name, so it literly means one value, like you have 10 rows 10 +  btn, at the you have just one  btn for plus and minus, your post dont know which plus or minus is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use ajax for this and make sure your buttons are dynamically populated with the id of the product.

```
     <button name="button_add_quantity" class="buttons_add_subtract" id="add_$data_id">+</button>
   <button name="button_subtract_quantity" class="buttons_add_subtract" id="minus_$data_id">-</button>
```

Both buttons now will have a unique id with prefix minus or add then the product id as a suffix.

Then using ajax handle the button clicks.

```
script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function(){
    //minus button

    $('[id^="minus_"]').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]; //get the id of the click product

        $.ajax({
          type :"POST",
          data : {id:index,action:"minus"},
          url  : "somefile.php",
          dataType : "json",
          encode : true,
          success : function(data){
            //after ajax success do something
            if(data == "ok"){
              //updated success
              location.reload();

            }else{

              alert(data); //alert the error
            }
          }
        });
  });

    //add button
    $('[id^="add_"]').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];

        $.ajax({
          type :"POST",
          data : {id:index,action:"add"},
          url  : "somefile.php",
          dataType : "json",
          encode : true,
          success : function(data){
            //after ajax success do something
            if(data == "ok"){
              //updated success
              location.reload();

            }else{

              alert(data); //alert the error
            }
          }
        });
  });

  });
</script>
```

Then

**somefile.php**

```
<?php
    include 'YOUR CONNECTION FILE';


    function minus($pdo_connection){

        $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id']:null;
            //update make sure does not go to negative quantity
        $statement_update = $pdo_connection->prepare("UPDATE finished_goods SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE product_id = ? AND quantity > 0 ")->execute([$id]);

        if($statement_update){

            echo json_encode("ok");//success
        }else{

            echo json_encode("error updating"); //error investigate the error
        }
    }

    function add($pdo_connection){

        $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id']:null;

        $statement_update = $pdo_connection->prepare("UPDATE finished_goods SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE product_id = ? ")->execute([$id]);

        if($statement_update){

            echo json_encode("ok");
        }else{

            echo json_encode("error updating"); //error investigate the error
        }
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){

        $request_action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action']:null;

        switch ($request_action) {
            case 'minus':
                minus($pdo_connection); // call the minus function
                break;

            case 'add':
                add($pdo_connection);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you get on the network tab of dev tool @shinbona

Comment: open developer tool and check the network tab of your browser as you click the button]